# how to get value from hash table in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, hashtable

I have a hash table in asp.net. This hash table returns two values for one key. And i need to get second(2nd)value from these two values for a corresponding key. 
How to get this value in asp.net using c#

Comment: What do you mean by "returns two values for one key"? How? Please show sample code.

Comment: how do you insert 2 values with the same key?  The keys should all be unique (though the .net API doesn't specify that as a requirement).

Comment: 1) What has this to do with asp.net? 2) what's your hashtable class? `Dictionary` has only a single value per key. Do you use a Dictionary with a tuple as value, or a `Lookup`?

Answer (score 1):

There is not such possibility in hash table that there is one key and multiple values, but it is possible that you store some list of values against a key.  Give sample code , so can understand it.

If you are storing a list of multiple values against a key then it is possible to get the 2nd value against the key. :)

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure I understand.

A hash-table has only one value per key. Could be that the value is a pair?

Give a code example and I'll edit with an answer (if I can).